# Edittext with 16digits along with hint and text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Edittext that represents an Debit card number. For those don't know debit card number has 16 digits. I want to present an empty edittext with 16 "-" characters with one space in every group of 4 "-". like below

HINT will be -> ---- ---- ---- ----

No i want every time the user inputs a number i want the 1st dash to be replaced by the number and leave 15 more left dashes. However, i want the dashes to be appear as hint text (meaning that the user will not be able to move the cursor to a specific dash) and the text that he inputs to be a regular text (meaning that he can select that or delete that)

How can i do that in Android

Comment: Does the below answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom solution for that. Actually, it's a hack but I suppose it will fulfill your requirement, I'm manipulating 'hint' text instead of the EditText 'text' property to control the Cursor. So, I wrote a simple Extension function for EditText which is mocking debit card format and restricting user to its format.

You can use this extension function in your Activity or Fragment like this

```kotlin
   // In your Fragment or Activity
        editTextDebitCard = findViewById(R.id.editTextDebitCard);
        editTextDebitCard.mockToDebitCard()
        // To get debit cardNumber (it will include spaces as well)
        val debitCardNumber =  editTextDebitCard.hint.toString()
```

Add this `mockToDebitCard` extension function to your project

```kotlin
fun EditText.mockToDebitCard() {
    val editTextDebitCard = this
    fun whenTypeBackOrDeleteTapped(hintText: String):String{
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(hintText.reversed())
        for((index,singleChar) in hintText.reversed().withIndex()){
            if(singleChar == ' '){
                continue
            }
            if(singleChar.isDigit()){
                stringBuilder[index] = '-'
                break
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString().reversed()
    }
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        fun getText(hintText: String, digit:String): String {
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(hintText)
            for((index,singleChar) in hintText.withIndex()){
                if(singleChar == ' '){
                    continue
                }
                if(!singleChar.isDigit()){
                    stringBuilder[index] = digit[0]
                    stringBuilder.toString()
                    break
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString()
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            if(editable.toString() != ""){
                val getHint = editTextDebitCard.hint.toString()
                val hintText = getText(getHint,editable.toString())
                editTextDebitCard.setHint(hintText)
                editTextDebitCard.setText("")
            }

        }
    })
    this.setOnKeyListener { view, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            val text = editTextDebitCard.hint.toString()
            val reversed = whenTypeBackOrDeleteTapped(text)

            editTextDebitCard.setHint(reversed)
            true // Return true to consume the key event
        } else {
            false // Return false to allow the system to handle other key events
        }
    }

}
```

Add your Fragment/Activity xml file

```xml
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDebitCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="---- ---- ---- ----"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColorHint="@color/mdtp_red"
        />
```

Do not forget to add `hint` and `inputType` properties in your XML file.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful please don't forget to up vote this answer.  Thanks